# Regarding a data recovery app from a play store

Tags: applications, google-play-store, data-recovery

I used one of the free data recovery app from the play store named **Photo recovery app** by **HappyAppsFree** on my old Samsung Galaxy S3 which I used after 2 years. I am worried as the privacy policies mentioned were not clear enough to figure out if my recovered data is also saved somewhere on the server side where developer can access it? I also tried to contact the developer on the given email address but no response. It's almost one year now that developer also updated the app but never responded to such questions.

My question is are such apps allowed to save the user's sensitive data we stored using their apps? The images recovered were of very poor quality.

Phone used was **Samsung galaxy s3**(most probably the old android version)

App used : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photo.recovery.deleted.video.recovery.recoverdeleted.photo

Comment: Your question is a bit too general and thus will be difficult to answer. You should better edit it and include more details like used Phone and Android version as well as the used recovery app.

Comment: "*Can ... ?*" the answer is almost always yes, also known as malware.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So this is the app available on the play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photo.recovery.deleted.video.recovery.recoverdeleted.photo

The phone was galaxy s3

Comment: Please read https://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask One of the main problems of your question is that it is unclear what you expect as answer. Andrew's comment is the actual answer to your question but I assume this is not your actual question. So please take one step back and think about what you really want to ask and then re-edit your question.

Comment: Thanks, I have explained the whole situation, I hope now I am able to ask my concern properly

Comment: *“My question is are such apps allowed to save the user's sensitive data”*. Well ***“allowed”*** doesn't matter. Theft and robbery is nowhere allowed, but it happens. That's why owners are supposed to take protective measures. You are the device owner. You installed the app and allowed it to access your data. Now only the app developer can tell if they stole your private data or not. // You might be interested in [Play Store User Data Policy](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/10144311).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If we delete the data using delete button of the app, can that data is still visible to the developer? Also, app states it performs read only operation, does that mean it is not writing anywhere?